# What are some nice words to describe one's body language when surprised?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

I constantly use the expressions

- He opened his eyes wide
- His jaw dropped
- He gasped in surprise

What others words/expressions can be used?

EDIT:

In this case, I'm looking for surprised in a good way

Comment: Surprised in a good way or bad? This is important.

Comment: @NVZ Edited. Forgot to mention that. In this case it would be surprised in a good way

Comment: I recommend that you take a look at [these idioms](http://www.learn-english-today.com/idioms/idiom-categories/surprise-disbelief/surprise.html)

Comment: The term used to describe the startle reaction is intransitive _start_. _He started (when I mentioned his name)._

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try, he/she *stood agape*.

Definitions of *agape*, via merriam webster online:

> having the mouth open because of wonder, surprise, or shock

Or:

> being in a state of wonder

Example:

> When James turned on the television to watch the basketball game, he stood agape at the massive score difference.

Answer (score 1):

***speechless with admiration***

> She was rendered speechless with admiration when she saw the results
>   of the landscaper's work, but quickly regained her composure and
>   lavishly praised the entire team.